# Running python code in a docker image in a server where I dont have root access

Tags: python, docker, ssh, server

So, I have access to a server by ssh with some gpus where I can run some python code. I need to do that using a docker container, however if I try to do anything with docker in the server i get permission denied as I dont have root access (and I am not in the list of sudoers). What am I missing here?
Btw, I am totally new to Docker (and quite new to linux itself) so it might be that I am not getting some fundamental.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use Ubuntu lts

Comment: You need to be in a group that allows access to the Docker daemon, so you'll need to ask the server administrator to add you to such a group.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought I had to do something myself. I'll ask then. Thanks!

Comment: Running a Docker container should almost always require root access (try `docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers` to give yourself sudo permissions if you don't already have it, for example).  If it's a Linux system, does it have a Python preinstalled that you can just use, without involving Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Turns out I simply had to ask the server administrator to add me to a group and everything worked.